# why does the mv command in bash delete files?

Tags: bash

running the following script to rename all .jpg files in the current folder works well sometimes, but it often deletes one or more files it is renaming. How would I write a script to rename files without deleting them in the process? This is running on Mac OSX 10.8 using GNU bash, version 3.2.48

this is an example file listing I would change for illustration:

original files

```
red.jpg
blue.jpg
green.jpg
```

renamed files if counter is set to 5

```
file_5.jpg
file_6.jpg
file_7.jpg
```

instead I get usually lose one or more files

```
#!/bin/bash  

counter=5

for file in *.jpg; do

    echo renaming "$file" to "file_${counter}.jpg";
    mv "$file" "file_${counter}.jpg";
    let "counter+=1";

done
```

### ** **UPDATE** **

it no longer seems to be deleting files, but the output is still not as expected. for example:

```
file_3.jpg
file_4.jpg
```

turns into

```
file_3.jpg
file_5.jpg
```

when counter is set to 4, when the expected output is

```
file_4.jpg
file_5.jpg
```

-

```
#!/bin/bash  

counter=3

for file in *.jpg; do

    if [[ -e file_${counter}.jpg ]] ; then
        echo Skipping "$file", file exists.
    else
        echo renaming "$file" to "file_${counter}.jpg"
        mv "$file" "file_${counter}.jpg"
    fi

    let "counter+=1"

done
```

Comment: Are you saying that one of the three 'coloured' JPG files goes missing when given a number — that you have a reproducible test case with the 3 input and (nominally) 3 output files cited in the question?  Or does it happen under other circumstances superficially similar to the colours/numbers example?  Are any of the original file names in the same format as the revised file names?

Comment: I guess it happens only if some files are already named file_*.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that some of the files already have names corresponding to the target names. For example, if there are files

```
file_1.jpg
file_7.jpg
```

and you start with `counter=7`, you overwrite `file_7.jpg` with `file_1.jpg` in the first step, and then rename it to `file_8.jpg`.

You can use `mv -n` to prevent clobbering (if supported), or test for existence before running the command

```
if [[ -e file_${counter}.jpg ]] ; then
    echo Skipping "$file", file exists.
else
    mv "$file" "file_${counter}.jpg"
fi
```

Comment: this helps in that it no longer deletes files, but it still has unexpected renaming behavior in certain situations as described in the questions update.

Comment: @waspinator: Then create a temporary directory, move all files there under the new names, move them back at the end and remove the dir.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are glazing over an obvious problem with the glob.  If the glob matches file_2.jpg, it will try and create file_file_2.jpg (I don't mean that in the literal sense, just that you will be reprocessing files you already processed).  To solve this, you need to make sure your initial glob expression doesn't match the files you have already moved:

```
shopt -s extglob

i=0
for f in !(file_*).jpg ; do
    while [[ -e "file_${i}.jpg" ]] ; do
        (( i++ ))
    done

    mv -v "$f" "file_$i.jpg"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What choroba said is correct. You can also use:

```
mv "$file" "file_${counter}.jpg" -n
```

to simply neglect the move when the destination filename already exists, or

```
mv "$file" "file_${counter}.jpg" -i
```

to ask whether it should overwrite or not.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over `*.jpg` you should skip your already renamed files i.e. `file_[0-9]*.jpg` and run your loop like this:

```
counter=5

while read file; do
   echo renaming "$file" to "file_${counter}.jpg";
   mv -n "$file" "file_${counter}.jpg";
   let "counter+=1";
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -not -name "file_[0-9]*.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to continue your counting until a file does not exist:

```
#!/bin/bash  

counter=1
shopt -s extglob

for file in *.jpg; do
    [[ $file == ?(*/)file_+([[:digit:]]).jpg ]] && continue

    until
        newname=file_$(( counter++ )).jpg
        [[ ! -e $newname ]]
    do
        continue
    done

    echo "renaming $file to $newname.";

    mv -i "$file" "$newname" ## Remove the -i option if you think it's safe already.
done
```

When doing things recursively:

```
#!/bin/bash  

shopt -s  extglob    
counter=1

while read file; do
    dirprefix=${file%%+([^/])

    until
        newfile=$dirprefix/file_$(( counter++ )).jpg
        [[ ! -e $newfile ]]
    do
        continue
    done

    echo "renaming $file to $newfile."

    mv -i "$file" "$newfile" ## Remove the -i option if you think it's safe already.
done < <(find -type f -name '*.jpg' -and -not -regex '^.*/file_[0-9]\+$')
```